# How to add multiple views to window manager in Android

Tags: android, android-view

[image: Android screenshot]

I am developing a application like [Facebook Chat Heads](http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/05/facebook-chat-heads-feature.html) a know how to add a single view to window manager.

How to add multiple views to window manager? I tried frame layout and relative layout, but how can I move chat head from one place to another place if I am using relative layout?

For adding multiple views I used below code:

```
chatHead = new ImageView(this);
    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    TextView t = new TextView(this);
    t.setText("Blessan Mathew");
    t.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childLayout.addView(t, params1);

    params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childLayout.addView(chatHead, params1);
    fr.addView(childLayout);

    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;
    windowManager.addView(fr, params);
```

How can I drag chat head to remove its view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add notification on top of `ImageView` and move both the views together:

Use `RelativeLayout` as parent Layout and add `ImageView` and `TextView` to it.

```
private RelativeLayout parentlayout;
TextView notification;

chatHead = new ImageView(this);
chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.deals);
chatHead.setId(imageid);
parentlayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

notification = new TextView(this);
notification.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#494949"));
notification.setText("1");
notification.setId(nameid);
notification.setTextSize(19);

final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_imageview = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params_imageview.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_name = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params_name.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, imageid);
params_name.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, imageid);

parentlayout.addView(chatHead, params_imageview);// adding user image to view
parentlayout.addView(notification, params_name);
```

Finally make these changes:

```
mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(parentlayout, params);
```

and

```
mWindowManager.addView(parentlayout, params);
```

PS: Use shapes to style `TextView` and get exact notification as that of Facebook!! :)

Comment: thank you for reply.. if i use above code both text view and image view are moving but i want to move a single view..like in the above photo i can drag chat head to cancel image

Comment: I am having the same issue!
I need to move the bubble around. But that doesnt happen as the Relative Layout is the parent for the bubble image. Any solution?